# Bootstrap columns act differently on I.E

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

The problem is that I want my code to display the same on I.E as it does on Chrome. I've only used bootstrap classes.

My Internet Explorer version is **11.356.18362.0**

Here's an image of the error I get:

[On the left how it's supposed to be (Chrome) and on the right is the broken version (I.E)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b6nqe.pnga)

Best way to test this error on your own computer is to copy-paste more card blocks

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<body class="m-5">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col">
        <div class="d-flex flex-row flex-wrap">
            <div class="card flex-fill">
                <div class="card-header">Block</div>

                <div class="card-body">
                    <div class="row form-group">
                        <label class="col-md-4 text-truncate">Text</label>
                        <div class="col-md-8">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row form-group">
                        <label class="col-md-4 text-truncate">Longerte</label>
                        <div class="col-md-8">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row form-group">
                        <label class="col-md-4 text-truncate">more text</label>
                        <div class="col-md-8">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row form-group">
                        <label class="col-md-4 text-truncate">and some more</label>
                        <div class="col-md-8">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row form-group">
                        <label class="col-md-4 text-truncate">Hello again</label>
                        <div class="col-md-8">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="card flex-fill">
                <div class="card-header">Block</div>

                <div class="card-body">
                    <div class="row form-group">
                        <label class="col-md-4 text-truncate">Text</label>
                        <div class="col-md-8">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row form-group">
                        <label class="col-md-4 text-truncate">Longerte</label>
                        <div class="col-md-8">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row form-group">
                        <label class="col-md-4 text-truncate">more text</label>
                        <div class="col-md-8">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row form-group">
                        <label class="col-md-4 text-truncate">and some more</label>
                        <div class="col-md-8">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row form-group">
                        <label class="col-md-4 text-truncate">Hello again</label>
                        <div class="col-md-8">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="card flex-fill">
                <div class="card-header">Block</div>

                <div class="card-body">
                    <div class="row form-group">
                        <label class="col-md-4 text-truncate">Text</label>
                        <div class="col-md-8">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row form-group">
                        <label class="col-md-4 text-truncate">Longerte</label>
                        <div class="col-md-8">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row form-group">
                        <label class="col-md-4 text-truncate">more text</label>
                        <div class="col-md-8">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row form-group">
                        <label class="col-md-4 text-truncate">and some more</label>
                        <div class="col-md-8">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row form-group">
                        <label class="col-md-4 text-truncate">Hello again</label>
                        <div class="col-md-8">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-auto">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header">Top to bottom</div>

            <div class="card-body"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: You need to explain your specific issue a bit more.

Comment: Since codepen cannot be open in IE, and your sample code is both working in chrome and IE, I really don't get what you mean by `Bootstrap columns broken on I.E`

Comment: I added an image

Comment: What version of IE are you using? Have you checked to ensure your version is actually compatible with the version of Bootstrap you're using? https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/browsers-devices/

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: Every error in my post should be fixed now. Sorry :D
@Lee On that site it says that my I.E version should be OK. (v. 11.356.18362.0)

Answer (score 0):

Seems your bootstrap coding format is incorrect, the format should be like follows:

```html
<section>
        <div class="conatiner">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    //inside this your code should goes.
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

and also try to avoid using "d-flex" classes which may give alignment issues in IE browsers only if "d-flex" classes not used properly.

if you want to remove space between two columns, simply make padding-left and padding-right properties to 0.